# More than one image crop box in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, crop

I'm looking for a jQuery script, for more than one crop mean different cropping on a single image.  Each crop box properties (width,height,x,y) should be displayed in textbox.

Dividing single image into different parts by user's selection.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a 'Please write my code' kinda site. You will have to show some effort to get others to respond.

Comment: Who upvoted a "plz give me the codez" question, which shows little researching effort? :/

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jquery JCrop Plugin](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) to get coordinates from user for the cropped image, you can save multiple coordinates as hidden fields while the process, and transfer it to backend to get different thumbnails for the image..